# Running a block of code synchronously, but contents have to run asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I have 3 queries (bigquery) that need to be executed asynchronously, but my further function call depends on the condition that all 3 queries have finished executing. How would I write a proper working code for this?

here's my demo code :

```
var flag = 0;
var defer = q.defer();
var defer2 = q.defer()
function promiseMeSomething() {
   var x =level2Queries()
   x.then(function SuccessPromise(input) {
        if (input == 3)
            defer.resolve(input);
        else
            defer.reject('Flag not set because value of flag is '+input);
    }, function (err) {
        console.error('Fail bro! ' + err)
    })


   console.log(defer.promise)
  return defer.promise;


}

function level2Queries() {

   q.fcall(bigquery.query(sqlQuery7).then(function Success() {
    flag++
}),
bigquery.query(sqlQuery8).then(function Success() {
    flag++
}),
bigquery.query(sqlQuery9).then(function Success() {
    flag++
})
)
defer2.resolve(flag);
return defer2.promise
}


var outputPromise = promiseMeSomething();
outputPromise.then(function (input) {
console.log(outputPromise)
}, function (input) {
console.log(outputPromise)
})
```

Comment: I think the function is called "all". It means All promises have to be fulfilled before it returns

Answer (score 2):

Combine the promises with all

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all